# Get key value pair from API call with Express and Request module

Tags: json, node.js, express, pug

I'm able to query an timetable API and return the full JSON response, using the request module. My end goal is to render the times using pug.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Salah' });
});

/* GET time page. */
router.get('/time', function(req, res, next) {
  var test = request({
    url: 'http://api.aladhan.com/timingsByCity',
    qs: {
      school: '1',
      country: 'uk',
      city: 'london'
    }
  }).timings.Sunrise.pipe(res);
  // }).pipe(res);
});

module.exports = router;
```

My current route `localhost:3000/time` renders [the same as this](http://api.aladhan.com/timingsByCity?city=london&country=uk&school=1). I'd like it to just return some specific timings, but I've had no luck using `.timings.Sunrise.pipe(res)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do something like:

```
router.get('/time', function(req, res) {
  request({
    url: 'http://api.aladhan.com/timingsByCity',
    qs: {
      school: '1',
      country: 'uk',
      city: 'london'
    }
  }, function(error, request, body) {
    var info = JSON.parse(body);
    res.render('showTimings', { timings: info.data.timings });
  });
});
```

*showTimings.pug*

```
ul
 for val, key in timings
   li= key + ': ' + val
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. So if I'm understanding this correctly, `body` is returned from the `request` function. We then do a JSON.parse on it so that we can step through it as we would in a rest client such as insomnia?

Comment: @m15m15m15, Absolutely, that's it.